# How to open file at particular line in GtkSource.View without visible flicker?

Tags: user-interface, pygtk, gtk3, gtksourceview

I need to open file in GtkSourceView and scroll to a particular line. Being a debugger gui of sorts, it needs to do this activity frequently (when switching stack frames), without transient artifacts - visible readjusting of the content and flickering. Currently, I am using the following approach:

```
from gi.repository import GtkSource
class MyClientWindow:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__sourceview = GtkSource.View()
    self.__sourceview.connect('size-allocate', self.__source_resize)
    ...
  def __source_resize(self, widget, allocation):
    self.__sourceview.scroll_to_mark(self.__sourceview.get_buffer().get_insert(), 0.25, False, 0, 0)
```

With this approach there is visible flicker. Placing 1s sleep in __source_resize above reveals that the GtkSourceView gets readjusted in a few passes (being visibly drawn before and after source highlighting, as well as some additional validation.)

Is there another way to force the GtkSource.View to compute line heights and perform validation without drawing on screen, or to force it to immediately compute line heights when I set the buffer content without deferring it to idle job later? If not, approximately how much of the GtkSource.View control would I need to override to get the desired behavior?

**Note:** I tried using Gtk.Stack to do the work in invisible "back" view and to make it visible later using Gtk.idle_add, but I got the impression that the visibility of the View is key to line validation. At least so far, it did not provide the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The Gtk.Stack method worked. It requires specific sequence of operations. This is excerpt (modified for clarity) from the solution I have now:

```
class MyClientWindow:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__stack = Gtk.Stack()
    ...
  def __switch_doc(content, line):
    buffer = GtkSource.Buffer()
    buffer.set_text(content)
    # buffer style settings are applied here
    ...
    iter = buffer.get_iter_at_line(line)
    buffer.place_cursor(iter)
    source_view = GtkSource.View.new_with_buffer(buffer)
    prev_sw = self.__stack.get_visible_child()
    next_sw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    next_sw.add(source_view)
    next_sw.show_all()
    self.__stack.add(next_sw)
    GObject.idle_add(lambda: self.__switch_view(prev_sw, next_sw))
  def __switch_view(self, prev_sw, next_sw):
    source_view = next_sw.get_child()
    buffer = source_view.get_buffer()
    source_view.scroll_to_iter(buffer.get_iter_at_mark(buffer.get_insert()), 0, True, 0, 0.5)
    if prev_sw:
      self.__stack.remove(prev_sw)
```

I recreate both the GtkSourceView and the parent GtkScrollWindow every time. This may be optimized somewhat (by holding on to old views in the stack instead of removing them.)

It is important that the GtkScrollWindow is shown before adding it to the stack container. Otherwise, it will lack coloring when shown later if scroll_to_iter is used to move to the new location in the text. (I couldn't figure if this is a bug.)

Showing the widget before adding it makes it the "visible child" of the stack, but only in sense that it gets returned by the get_visible_child method. It does not however render it to the screen.

The drawing begins when the old child is removed (or the new one is activated with the set_visible_child method), which due to the use of idle_add above, happens after line validation of GtkSourceView. Thus, the scrolling can be performed with scroll_to_iter, instead of scroll_to_mark, which would defer the action even further.